# ¿Porque mi array no almacena esta variable?

Tags: java

Tengo un array de clases, en este caso ProductsA. lo estoy recorriendo con el for each,

```
Products []productsA = new Products[3];
productsA[0] = new Products("perfum",50);
productsA[1] = new Perishable("tv",400,2);
productsA[2] = new Nonperishable("phone",
            200,"electrodomestico");

for(Products i:productsA) {
        int totalPrice = i.getPrice()*5;
        array = {totalPrice};
```

esa ultima linea me marca un error (Array constants can only be initializers).
quiero que en cada vuelta guardar ese resultado en el array para despues sumarlo y recorrerlo.
por cierto lo tengo de forma global.

```
int array[];
```

ademas intente con el bucle for normal y marca mas errores solo pude con este

Comment: Si array es un array de numeros, en que posicion del array queres guardar totalPrice?

Comment: Estás utilizando el formato de Array `{ <elems> }` que sólo puede usarse al momento de inicializar un Array. Deberías almacenar cada elemento usando el valor del índice adecuado. Saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres guardar el precio total en cada posición del *array*? Sería más fácil si en la clase `Producto` agregaras un campo llamado `totalPrice`, de este modo, evitas el *array*. Dentro del *foreach* solo debes hacer esto: `i.setTotalPrice(i.getPrice()*5);` (claro, el **setter** lo debes definir en la clase **Producto**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas saber la posición en la que guardaras el totalPrice, podría ser algo asi:

```
    int[] array = new int[3];
    int c = 0;
    for (Products i : productsA) {
        int totalPrice = i.getPrice() * 5;
        array[c] = totalPrice;
        c++;
    }
```

Comment: amigo la verdad no soluciona nada dice que la variable local no debe ser inicializada

Comment: Puedes subir el código completo por favor?

Comment: Listo amigo ya.

Comment: @mauricio Edité la respuesta, se crea una variable nueva (un arreglo) que es el que usarás posteriormente para guardar los precios.